# How does one pass a factory module into another?

Tags: jquery, module, angularjs

I have two custom methods I'm setting up. One for Global communication throughout the app, and another to handle http requests. My http request module requires my GlobalService to operate. How do I pass my GlobalService provider into my CustomHTTP provider?

**CustomHTTP**

```
angular.module("customHTTPService", []).factory("$chttp", [
  "$http", "GlobalService", function($http, $parse) {
    var chttp;
    return chttp = function(method, url) {
      return $http({
        method: method,
        url: GlobalService.apiRoot + url
      }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return [data, status, headers, config];
      }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        return [data, status, headers, config];
      });
    };
  }
]);
```

**My globalService provider**

```
angular.module('GlobalService', []).factory("GlobalService", function($rootScope) {
  var sharedService, _ref;
  sharedService = {};
  return sharedService.apiRoot = (_ref = window.location.hostname) === "0.0.0.0" || _ref === "localhost" ? "http://localhost:3000/api/" : "http://website.com/api/";
});
```

**And finally.. my app instantiation**

```
window.app = angular.module('web_client', ['GlobalService', 'customHTTPService'], function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {});
```

So then to test this, I throw this in one of my controllers :

```
this.SettingsController = function($scope, $location, GlobalService, $http, $chttp) {
  $.v = $chttp;
};
```

And then I try to run it in console..

```
$.v('get', '/index.html');
```

Which returns :

```
ReferenceError: GlobalService is not defined
```

Or even a little more upstream, if I put this within my customHTTPService module.. :

```
console.log(GlobalService);
```

I get the same error.

What's the proper way to pass modules to one another? Is there something I could be doing better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `customHTTPService` module needs to list the `GlobalService` module as a dependency.

```
angular.module("customHTTPService", ['GlobalService'])
```

However, first you need to change so that your `GlobalService` is defined before `customHTTPService`, otherwise the dependency will fail.

You can read more about modules and dependencies [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module).